# multi wildcard target in Makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Just simple Makefile:

```
a/% b/%:
    @echo $@
```

When I do

> make a/a b/b

It's OK as expected that:

> a/a
>
> b/b

But when I do

> make a/a b/a

It's appears that:

> a/a
>
> make: Nothing to be done for `b/a'.

How can I get the expect return

> a/a
>
> b/a

Tested with make version both v3.81 and v3.82 on Linux and macOS

Comment: There has nothing to do with `.PHONY`. This is a test for the actual Makefile. Even if there is `.PHONY: a/% b/%` in the simple Makefile, take no effect.

Answer (score 0):

Given your `makefile`...

```
a/% b/%:
        @echo $@
```

Consider what happens when you invoke `make a/a b/b`.  `make` notices that the rule `a/% b/%:` matches with the stem `a` (i.e. the built in variable `$*` will be `a`) and runs the command.  Because your rule has multiple targets `make` now considers both `a/a` *and* `b/a` to have been updated.

Make then considers the next target specified on the command line `b/b`.  That hasn't yet been updated and so `make` runs the same rule again but with the stem `b`.  So the rule is run twice -- once for each pattern stem `a` and `b`.

Now consider what happens when you invoke `make a/a b/a`.  This time both targets will match the same rule but with the same stem `a`.  Hence `make`, having run the rule with the stem `a` considers both `a/a` and `b/a` to have been updated and sees no need to rerun the rule for second command line target `b/a`.

It's not entirely clear what behaviour you require but if you want the same rule to be invoked multiple times for different targets even though the pattern stem is the same then you might want something like...

```
# Possible targets (for illustration purposes).
#
TARGETS := a/a a/b b/a b/b

$(TARGETS): %:
        @echo $@
```

The above gives...

> G.M.> make -f multi-wildcard-target-in-makefile.mk a/a b/b
> a/a
> b/b
>
> G.M.> make -f multi-wildcard-target-in-makefile.mk a/a b/a
> a/a
> b/a

Comment: Thank you, I get it. And is there some way to make `make` run more than once with the wildcard targets? Or it's impossible? The actual rules like this

Comment: `$(MAKE) -C $(@D) $(@F)`, so I can't write the actual targets in Makefile. (The stem is unknown).

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I understand your comments.  If you can provide a more concrete example of what you actually require I'd be happy to update my answer.

Comment: I mean that the recipe of target `a/% b/%:` is `$(MAKE) -C $(@D) $(@F)`. So the stem `%` actually is the target in `a/Makefile` or `b/Makefile`, and it's unexpected.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to hardcode possible targets as G.M. proposed, you may make some magic:

```
$ cat Makefile
define recipe
$(1):
    @echo $$@
endef

PATTERNS=a/% b/%
$(foreach pattern,$(PATTERNS),$(eval $(call recipe,$(pattern))))
```

Testing:

```
$ make a/a b/a
a/a
b/a
$ make a/a b/b
a/a
b/b
```

The behavior you observe is described in [GNU make docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Intro.html#Pattern-Intro):

> Pattern rules may have more than one target. Unlike normal rules, this does not act as many different rules with the same prerequisites and recipe. If a pattern rule has multiple targets, make knows that the rule’s recipe is responsible for making all of the targets. The recipe is executed only once to make all the targets.

Comment: Thank you, I get it. This can solve the problem. But if the **make docs** said **The recipe is executed only once to make all the targets.**, why `make a/a b/b` in my description can be executed twice?

Comment: Once for a given `%`. First, `%` is evaluated to `a`, and make will execute rule as if `a/a b/a`. Then, make needs to build `b/b` (as you requested it), so `%` becomes `b` and make will execute rule as if `a/b b/b`. This is what G.M. explained in his answer.